# Custom ProgressBar with default ProgressBar theme

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, progress-bar

I am trying to understand how to customize or create a .NET ProgressBar with no borders and with square shaped corners. The main reason why I'm not trying to use custom progress bars already available is that I have not found any with the same theme as the System Default Progress Bar.

So I have three questions.

1. How can I remove the border from a progress bar?
2. How can I show a progress bar with square corners?
3. How do I get the system default ProgressBar theme to use in a custom control?

I have a doubt that the first two are possible or not but I think the third one can be done even though I have not idea how to do it.

### UPDATE:

Somehow the following code solves the first two questions but a new problem arises that when the value of the progress bar is `1` it shows no progress. I believe that is not a major problem but ideally it should not be the case.

```
class ProgressBarEx : ProgressBar
{
    const int WmPaint = 15;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);

        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WmPaint:
                using (var graphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(Handle))
                {
                    GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();

                    Rectangle newRectangle = ClientRectangle;

                    newRectangle.Inflate(-2, -2);

                    path.AddRectangle(newRectangle);

                    Region = new Region(path);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

### UPDATE 2:

I managed to 'fix' the `Value` by declaring a new Property for the custom progressbar, `percentProgress` and utilizing it to set the real `Value`;

```
this.Value = Convert.ToInt32(((((float)percentProgress / 100f) * (float)98) + 1) / 100f) * ((float)Maximum - (float)Minimum));
```

I'll leave this question open for some more time just in case anyone has a better solution.

Comment: WPF? WinForms? ASP? GTK#? What UI framework are you working on?

Comment: @RonBeyer Oh. Sorry. Forgot to mention. It's winforms.

Comment: This would be very simple if you were using WPF, but winforms is a different monster. You're basically better off creating a new control, inheriting from `ProgressBar`, and handling the paint event.

Comment: @RonBeyer I did try to handle the paint event and excluded the border of the progress bar but that made the bar not show any progress when the width of the progress bar is 100 or less pixels, and the `Value` is `1` and similarly when `Value` is `99` it will appear as if it were `100`.

Comment: When you override the paint event, you take over ALL the painting, not just the parts you want to exclude. Show your code of the paint event you tried, we can point to what you did wrong.

Comment: You shouldn't be using WndProc to handle painting, use the OnPaint event, or override the Paint method.

Comment: I tried overriding the `OnPaint` but apparently that does not work for ProgressBars. [However buttons work using the `OnPaint` and I did not try other controls]

Comment: Also you are ignoring the fill part, you are just drawing the background. You need to calculate and draw the fill based on the progress value. See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26518/Custom-ProgressBar-Control or search google for "winforms custom progress bar"

Comment: I actually did a search on the custom progress controls available out there but I have not found a single one which can display the default progress bar style.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Ron Beyer comment, try searching CodeProject.com if you want to save time. see this as example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31906/Progress-O-Doom